# Visual Basic needs to change from MySQL to MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

I have an existing app, simple single table data lookup that was written to connect to MySQL and I need to change it to MSSQL.  The connection strings look straight forward, but I don't know how to change them to point the the already converted MSSQL table.

Comment: Don't you have a data control? You probably can make the connection with it and then copy the connection string to put in your code. This is what I used to do during my VB days :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following website to generate the correct connection string for your sql server installation:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Comment: I have a data control binding, but there are references to a MySQL data structure for the connection information and I'm not finding the same structure when using SQL Server.